# how to quote multi-columns in lambda function using with_columns

Tags: lambda, apply, multiple-columns, python-polars

Sometimes the multi-columns need to be applied complex logical process in lambda.
The example can't work if column a or b contains null value.( handling null value for example here, actual process logical can be much complex)

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [7, 2, 3, 4],
    "b": ['2', '5', None, '7'],})
df.with_columns((pl.col('a')+pl.col('b')).alias('sum'))
```

result:

| a | b | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| i64 | str | f64 |
| 3 | null | null |
| 4 | 7 | 11 |

My expection:

| a | b | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| i64 | str | f64 |
| 3 | null | 3 |
| 4 | 7 | 11 |

my solution:

```
def my_sum(x):
    x0= x[0] if x[0] is not None else 0
    x1= x[1] if float(x[1]) is not None else 0
    return x0+x1
df.hstack(df.apply(lambda x:my_sum(x))).rename({"apply": "sum"})
```

Is there any more graceful method to do this job?
How to quote multi-columns in lambda function using with_columns like apply?

Answer (score 1):

You can cast string column to integer using [cast method](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.cast.html#polars.Expr.cast) and fill null values to zero using [fill_null method](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.fill_null.html#polars.Expr.fill_null).
And then perform the required operation.

Here is how:

```py
df = df.with_columns(pl.col("b").cast(pl.Int64).fill_null(0))
df = df.with_columns((pl.col("a") + pl.col("b")).alias("sum_ab"))

# Output

shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ sum_ab │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64    │
╞═════╪═════╪════════╡
│ 7   ┆ 2   ┆ 9      │
│ 2   ┆ 5   ┆ 7      │
│ 3   ┆ 0   ┆ 3      │
│ 4   ┆ 7   ┆ 11     │
└─────┴─────┴────────┘
```

Comment: OP doesn't want their B changed so I think you want just a one-liner `df.with_columns((pl.col("a") + pl.col("b").cast(pl.Int64).fill_null(0)).alias("sum_ab")`

Comment: It works thank you . But what I am looking for is  something like df.with_columns((apply(lambda:func(pl.col('a'),pl.col('b'))).alias('sum'))  . The func may be extreme complex.

Comment: @bestathena there are number of [expression methods](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/index.html) available in Polars other than summation. You can find out which one to use depending on your use case.

Comment: @dikesh Thanks. But is there any way to use two or more columns in  one lambda function to adding a new  column?  Expression methods  may be insufficient for some complex conditions.